# Simple css not working in Iceweasel 31.2

Tags: javascript, html, css, iceweasel

So I am making a website for a relative, I have made a  which isn't displayed at first (display : none) and fades in when the user click somewhere on the page.
It works very well with Chromium, but when I try with Iceweasel 31.2 the CSS for the part of the page that is supposed to fade-in doesn't load.

The javascript function that is called upon clicking the button :

```
var openGallery = function(){
    $('section, nav, #topleft').fadeOut(400);
    $('#gallerie').toggle();
}
```

This is the CSS involved

```
#gallerie
{
position: relative;
height: 874px;
width: 1152px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
border-radius: 5px;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}

#gallerie img:first-of-type
{
max-width: 1100px;
max-height: 720px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.close
{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
top: 5px;
}

.left, .right
{
position: static;
top: 746px;
}
```

And finally, the HTML that fades in/out (note that the JS part of it comes from some PHP)

```
<div id="gallerie">
<script type="text/javascript">
var collection = [
    // "FILENAME" | "NAME" | WIDTH | HEIGHT
    ["6ème arrondissement-73 X 60.JPG","6ème arrondissement",1535,1832],
    (more data...)
    ["Sur la neige-55 X 46.JPG","Sur la neige",1853,1562]
]
</script>
    <h3>Gallerie</h3>
    <figure>
        <img src="data/tableaux/6ème arrondissement-73 X 60.JPG" class="big" title="6ème arrondissement" alt="0">
        <figcaption>6ème arrondissement</figcaption>
        <img src="images/left.png" alt="left" class="left" title="left"><img src="images/right.png" alt="right" class="right" title="right">
    </figure>
    <img src="images/close.png" class="close" title="Fermer la fenetre">
</div>
```

I really don't know where the bug might come from. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Would you mind creating a fiddle for others to see your problem more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use JQuery to toggle through the class events and use those to do the transitions etc. Right now, CSS3 is pretty good across browsers.

Instead of:

```
$('section, nav, #topleft').fadeOut(400);
```

I would add CSS that handles the fade with a transition.

Check out the pen I made here to see the effect. You can add toggleClass(); addClass(); or removeClass(); should you choose.

http://codepen.io/brycesnyder/pen/LEPJZg

EDIT: .toggle(); will cause a stupid effect, I meant .toggleClass();